# How to jump to specific line of a file when file path and line number is given?

Tags: key-bindings, navigation

I have a filename and its line provided in this format, e.g.:

```
./my_dir/my_filename.py:20:
```

When I move on the filename and press `gf` I jump to that file, however the cursor stands on line number 1, instead of 20. How could i make `gf` respect the line number? I am using [lervag/file-line](https://github.com/lervag/file-line) plugin, which usually handles similar cases, e.g. when `./my_dir/my_filename.py:20:` is provided as a command-line argument for Vim.

Answer (score 3):

See [`:h gF`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#gF):

```
                            *gF*
[count]gF       Same as "gf", except if a number follows the file
            name, then the cursor is positioned on that line in
            the file. The file name and the number must be
            separated by a non-filename (see 'isfname') and
            non-numeric character.
```

So using <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Shift-f</kbd> should do the trick.